# window.open not working inside action.setCallback

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

From a lightning component I have to open a url but the problem I need to do the check before, and for that I created action.setCallBack where my check is done.

the problem here is that window.open ('URL'); it is not running.
is there any solution for that ?

```
    redirect : function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.method");
        var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setParams({ 
            Id : component.get("v.recordId")});
        action.setCallback (this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS"){
                component.set("v.recordId", response.getReturnValue());
                if (response.getReturnValue() != condition){  
                    window.open(**URL**) ;
                }               
            }  
 });
 $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: Could you please add a `console.log` just before the condition where the `window.open` is, also `console.log( response.getReturnValue() )`and please add a chrome extension(if you are using chrome) that detects all the Lightning errors - Salesforce Lightning Inspector. Also please share as to what you have specifically written in the `window.open` method

Comment: well, I checked the console.log , and seems that everything works fine as expected. if I call the windows.open just before closing the redirect, it works fine.

Comment: Could you please add the extension and look for some errors that generally are not pooped in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was just to replace it by this function and call it.

function urlEvent() {
            location.href = 'URL';
}

Comment: Can you please add some more relevant code part and explain it? How it is working, where you created this function?

Answer (score 1):

Using below code you can navigate form lightning.

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
   "url": someurl   
});
urlEvent.fire();
```

Comment: To the point answer and +10 for that but the standard events for Lightning do not work when the component is embedded inside a VF page.

Comment: OP is wondering why window.open is not working from callback in her case, and perhaps not exploring alternatives yet.

Comment: @MohitArora are you talking about Lightning Out? Thanks for cleafication :)

Comment: @Kal whenever you create a lightning Component Salesforce create Iframe. that's why it cause issue for redirecting. For redirection we always use this in our apps

Comment: @ChandraKiran Yes, embedding a lightning component in a VF page and using a lightning component in ltng:out are nearly the same because in both ways they use the same script to render a lightning component. The standard events are only handled by one.app container in lightning.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add a possible reason why this `window.open` failed in the first place.

Browsers are increasingly designed to prevent unwanted pop-up windows. As a result, if you try and open a brand new window that is not in direct response to an interaction (click, keystroke etc) by the user, the built-in pop-up blocker usually stops it.

Because you are doing asynchronous work between the user's interaction and the `window.open`, the browser no longer considers it to be in direct response to user interaction and blocks the pop-up. So one alternative, as you have noted, is a same-window redirect. Another alternative is a flow that opens the window immediately in response to an interaction and then does the processing. For example you could open a Visualforce page in the new window that runs your decision logic in the Apex controller and then either does a redirect or closes itself.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your `$A.enqueueAction(action);` is outside the scope of `redirect` method. Perhaps that? Throw in a `console.log` in your callback and see if it shows up at all in browser logs?

```
redirect : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.method");
    var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
    action.setParams({ 
        Id : component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback (this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS"){
            component.set("v.recordId", response.getReturnValue());
            console.log('---------> SUCCESS ' + component.get("v.recordId"));
            if (response.getReturnValue() != condition){  
                window.open('<URL>');
            }               
        }
        else
            console.log('---------> ERROR ');
    }
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

And on a side note: depending on the URL you are trying to redirect to, perhaps  [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) would be a more prudent approach...?

Comment: no it is inside, it was just a mistakke when creating the question.